# changing key names when leveraging laravel resources to return API data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.7, laravel-resource

So I am currently building out an API and see that laravel has added an API resource which I am assuming is in lieu of something like fractal?

However running into an issue where when I go to return a collection using the XyzCollection resource I do not have the ability to change my DB names? So i end up with the same naming convention I have in my DB..

Plenty of obvious reasons why I don't want to have that be the case (i can go into them if need be) HOWEVER - is there a way to alter those key names?

for example in one of my tables I have a id,uuid,user_uuid
Now in fractal I would just transform these fields like so -

```
'id' => $xyz->uuid, 
'user' => [
    'data' => [
        [
        'user_id' => $xyz->user->uuid,
        'username' => $xyz->user->username,
        ]
    ]
],
```

How do i do this when all i can do is pass in the collectionin the XyzCollection?

```
'data' => $this->collection,
```

and before you say use XyzResource ... When I am returning all(); records like I need to do plenty of times in an API (or paginate) etc etc. I can only do that from XyzCollection!

Thanks in advance

Steve

Comment: Does your collection derive from a model? If so, you could try extending the model to a new model that is only used by the API. You could then make appended attributes with the names you want, and hide the original attribute names by using the $hidden array on the model. This is a little more elegant than using mapping or loops to rename things programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define a structure for a *singular* JsonResource object:

(`php artisan make:resource Xyz`)

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'user_id' => $this->uuid,
        'username' => $this->username,
    ];
}
```

And then tell your XyzCollection to use the class:

> #### Customizing The Underlying Resource Class
>
> Typically, the
>   `$this->collection` property of a resource collection is automatically
>   populated with the result of mapping each item of the collection to
>   its singular resource class. The singular resource class is assumed to
>   be the collection's class name without the trailing `Collection`
>   string.
>
> For example, `UserCollection` will attempt to map the given user
>   instances into the `User` resource. To customize this behavior, you may
>   override the `$collects` property of your resource collection

(From https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-resources#concept-overview)

If your ResourceCollection doesn't do anything extra, you might not always need it. Every JsonResource can transform itself into a resource collection with the `collection()` method, e.g. `UserResource::collection($users)`

Comment: just getting a chance to look at this - From a glance at what you posted from the docs I think this might have hit the nail on the head - dont know how I missed the $collects override - will report back when I dig into this!

Comment: ugh I know how I missed the override! just went back to my docs page open and it was on v5.5! must have been the version I came in from through googling! FUNNNNNN!!!!!!

Comment: Ok all - so clearly version 5.7 of the docs lay it out much nicer :) MY FAULT. So the piece of the puzzle i was missing was that -> "resource collection is automatically populated with the result of mapping each item of the collection to its singular resource class" once I changed the naming so it actually picked it up properly - Its now picking up my collections exactly the way I want to display them! Thanks @Travis